# How to properly validate Twitter's Bootstrap form placed on several tabs with jQuery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jquery-validate

I have one form located on several Twitter's Bootstrap tabs:

```
<form id="personal-data" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="tabbable">
    <ul id="tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>

    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="field1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="field2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>          
      </div>
```

When I `valid`ate the form with jQuery validate on active tab and field with invalid value is on the same tab, then validation fails (which is correct). But when I am on one tab and invalid value is on another tab, then validation returns `true`, which is incorrect. How can I fix it? How can I highlight that field on another tab?

Please see [this demo](http://jsbin.com/emozep/2) (just press button *next* - it will show error message, then go to last tab and press *finish* there).

Answer (score 15):

I think your problem lies in the fact that validation occurs in visible elements only.

Reading this [issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/279) we see that on version 1.9

> Fixed #189 - :hidden elements are now ignored by default

and a solution a few comments down

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""
});
```

Comment: a very simple/naive approach would be to find the first element with error class -> get the tab containing it -> switch to tab. But this is another question which someone might answer better

Answer (score 3):

My solution to enable tabs

```
...
highlight: function(label) {
        $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');

        $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.error)").each( function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#tabs a[href="#'+id+'"]').tab('show');
        });
},
...
```

Is necessary that you add this code to allow change tab by js

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your code it solved most of my problem, except the part to navigate to first tab with error. I got around as follows:

```
        var IsValid = true;

        // Validate Each Bootstrap tab
        $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane").each(function (index, tab) {
            var id = $(tab).attr("id");
            $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');

            var IsTabValid = $("#SomeForm").valid();

            if (!IsTabValid) {
                IsValid = false;
            }
        });

        // Show first tab with error
        $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane").each(function (index, tab) {
            var id = $(tab).attr("id");
            $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');

            var IsTabValid = $("#SomeForm").valid();

            if (!IsTabValid) {
                return false; // Break each loop
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these jQuery tabs you're using? You can deactivate all other tabs and gradually activate them while the submitted data on each form pass the validation. Disable them all but the first in your constructor and after each validation enable the next.

```
.tabs( "enable" , index )
```

Read more [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

You could also put one final validation method in the end and put all your content visible depending on the tabs so you can escape the reloading of the links.

Comment: I use Twitter Bootstrap and its tabs - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [@juanmanuele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806372/114029), this is how I managed to get it working with [Bootstrap 3 tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

```
if($(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane.active:has(div.has-error)").length == 0)
{
    $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function(index, tab)
    {
        var id = $(tab).attr("id");

        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
    });
}
```

To place focus on the 1st input with error:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e)
{
     e.target // activated tab

     $($(e.target).attr('href')).find("div.has-error :input:first").focus();

     //e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```

Comment: Nice one, I only added a `return false;` after the `$('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');` part since I had problems with 2+ tabs

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the solution for jQuery Validate, but you could use the "invalid" event on form elements, to catch HTML5 validation errors, and get the focused element, find the respectively tab-pane, and show it.

I have done this.

```
$("form").find("input, select").on("invalid", function() {
  var id = $(this).parents(".tab-pane").attr("id");

  $("#tabs-selector ul").find("li a[href='#" + id + "']").tab("show");
});
```

Hope this helps you. Again, this is for HTML5 or if jQuery Validate fires an invalid event.