# jQuery Validate not working on Bootstrap 3 tabbed form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jquery-validate

I have looked at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336409/2173793), and many more like it, but I still cant get my form validation to switch tabs or move to the tab with the error.

Relevant jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("form[name=modify]").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true,
        },
        surname: {
            required: true
        },
        id_number: {
            required: true
        },
        mobile_number: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
        },
        home_number: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
        },
        other_contact: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
        },
        line1: {
            required: true,
        },
        city_town: {
            required: true,
        },
        postal_code: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
        },
        curr_renumeration: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
        },
        expect_renumeration: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        email: {
            email: true,
            required: true,
        },
        highlight: function (label) {
            $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
            console.log($(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error'));
            if ($(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane.active:has(div.has-error)").length == 0) {
                $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                    var id = $(tab).attr("id");

                    $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                });
                $('#myTab').on('shown', function (e) {
                    console.log(this);
                    e.target // activated tab
                    $($(e.target).attr('href')).find("div.has-error :input:first").focus();
                });
            }
        },
    }
});
$("[type=submit]").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

});

});
```

You can view it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/cyPz6/3/)

What am I missing?

Can someone please help me? I cant get it to work.

**UPDATE:**

Okay so I have moved some code around and played a bit:

```
$("form[name=modify]").validate({
        highlight : function(label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            $(".tab-content").find("fieldset.tab-pane:has(has-error)").each(function(index, tab) {
                alert("error from if");
                if ($(".tab-content").find("field.tab-pane.active:has(has-error)").length == 0) {
                    alert("error from each");
                    var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                    console.log(id);
                    $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                }

            });
        },
        invalidHandler : function(event, validator) {
            // 'this' refers to the form
            $('#myTab').on('shown', function(e) {
                console.log(this);
                e.target;// activated tab
                $($(e.target).attr('href')).find("fieldset.has-error :input:first").focus();
            });
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                $("div.has-error span").html(message);
                $("div.has-error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.has-error").hide();
            }
        },
        ignore : [],
        rules : {
            first_name : {
                required : true,
            },
            surname : {
                required : true
            },
            id_number : {
                required : true
            },
            mobile_number : {
                number : true,
                minlength : 10,
            },
            home_number : {
                number : true,
                minlength : 10,
            },
            other_contact : {
                number : true,
                minlength : 10,
            },
            line1 : {
                required : true,
            },
            city_town : {
                required : true,
            },
            postal_code : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 4,
            },
            curr_renumeration : {
                required : true,
                number : true,
            },
            expect_renumeration : {
                required : true,
                number : true
            },
            email : {
                email : true,
                required : true,
            },

        }
    });
```

All works well, except it stops at this line `if ($(".tab-content").find("field.tab-pane.active:has(has-error)").length == 0) {`

and if I swop it with `$(".tab-content").find("fieldset.tab-pane:has(has-error)").each(function(index, tab) {` it stop as well...

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/cyPz6/5/)

Why does it not go into the `.each` or th`if` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

I have solved my problem...

I had to adjust this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336409/2173793) a bit.

My solution was:

- Inside my `$("form[name=modify]").validate({})` I called a function named `highlight`,
- Instead of using `$(".tab-content")`, I used the paramater `label` to create a variable:

  ```
  var tab_content=$(label).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
  ```
- Maybe not the most efficient way nor the best way to do it... but it works..
- I also removed `:hidden` from this line:

  ```
  $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)").each(function(index, tab)
  ```

Here is the complete function:

```
        $("form[name=modify]").validate({
        highlight : function(label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            var tab_content= $(label).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
            if ($(tab_content).find("fieldset.tab-pane.active:has(div.has-error)").length == 0) {                   
                 $(tab_content).find("fieldset.tab-pane:has(div.has-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                    var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                 });
             }
          },
            ignore : [], // <-- this is important
            rules : {
                first_name : {
                    required : true,
                },
                surname : {
                    required : true
                },
                id_number : {
                    required : true
                },
                mobile_number : {
                    number : true,
                    minlength : 10,
                },
                home_number : {
                    number : true,
                    minlength : 10,
                },
                other_contact : {
                    number : true,
                    minlength : 10,
                },
                line1 : {
                    required : true,
                },
                city_town : {
                    required : true,
                },
                postal_code : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 4,
                },
                curr_renumeration : {
                    required : true,
                    number : true,
                },
                expect_renumeration : {
                    required : true,
                    number : true
                },
                email : {
                    email : true,
                    required : true,
                },

            }
        });
```

Check it out on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/cyPz6/6/)

- **Note:** You do not need the extra function to swap tabs as stated in the answer mentioned above:

  ```
  // Don't need this 
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
      e.target // activated tab

      $($(e.target).attr('href')).find("div.has-error :input:first").focus();

      //e.relatedTarget // previous tab
  });
  ```

I do not know why, but you do not need it... Mine works without it anyway...

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 17):

I think your trouble might be that jquery by default will only validate visible fields. So what you need to do is tell jquery to not ignore your hidden fields (other tabs). This can be done as follows.

```
$("#form1").validate({ ignore: "" });
```

By default, ignore `:hidden`. See this answer, and this documentation (Options -> Ignore).

Comment: Great, Glad that this helped you

Answer (score 9):

```
$("form").on('submit', function () {
    var isValid = $(this).valid();
    if (this.hasChildNodes('.nav.nav-tabs')) {
        var validator = $(this).validate();
        $(this).find("input").each(function () {
            if (!validator.element(this)) {
                isValid = false;
                $('a[href=#' + $(this).closest('.tab-pane:not(.active)').attr('id') + ']').tab('show');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    if (isValid) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```